# Nodejs req.body shows empty from Android Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Android Code:

```
private void registerUser(){
        final String username = "subrata";
        final String password = "banerjee";
        final String email = "test_email";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I'm trying to send `http` request using *Android Volley* to my node.js server (expressjs). Its hitting the server and getting the response but when I'm printing the `req.body` in node.js its shows `{}` (empty). I'm new to Android and unable to figure out the reason. Please someone guide me.

Comment: what does toast showing in OnResponse method?

Comment: Its shows the response json. Its correct.

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar The problem is with the Android Volley request. I googled and found that it has something to do with charset but really don't know how to implement.

Comment: Then you have to parse Json using the Json object, check my answer i will post a demo method for you.

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Unable to see your answer here Sir.

Comment: If you are getting the response, then what's the issue with the volley request? Just added the answer have a look

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Problem is with `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`. How do I set the header?

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar Pleae check this link http://envyandroid.com/android-volley-empty-parameters/

Comment: In your shown example if you want to set header like that then you can set like `params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar let me try

Comment: @MayankBhatnagar I tried your way but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Call this method in OnResponse `GetResponse(response);`
And the method will be

```
private void GetResponse(String res){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
            String temp = jo.getString("what_ever");
            String temp1 = jo.getString("what_ever_1");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will get you the response in String format fetched from json.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void registerUser(){
       JSONObject jsonBodyObj = new JSONObject();
        try{
            jsonBodyObj.put("mAtt", "+1");
            jsonBodyObj.put("mDatum","+2");
            jsonBodyObj.put("mRID","+3");
            jsonBodyObj.put("mVon","+4");
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final String requestBody = jsonBodyObj.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("User-agent", "My useragent");
                return headers;
            }
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                            requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```